# Netflix UI - what webframework technology and server architecture is being used

Tags: node.js, frontend, netflix

What Web technology and Web server architecture is used for Netflix Website?

Is it NodeJS/Angular and all running on EC2(s) or there is serverless technology involved for front end UI using lambda etc?

Comment: Microservices at Netflix - https://www.nginx.com/blog/microservices-at-netflix-architectural-best-practices/amp/

Comment: Netflix medium blogs - https://medium.com/netflix-techblog